# Unable to insert the file in the folder

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to insert attachment file from Slaesforce, everything works great, except I am unable to insert into a folder.

```
CALLOUT_REQUEST|[283]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/0B-tXgc3jNMFHWk1wMTNRdW9qVmM?uploadType=media, Method=PUT]
CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[283]|System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]
```

If you see the response here, I am appending the folder id also in the End point URL, however it is getting inserted into root folder. Could anyone suggest me what to do?

Regards,
Ajay

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I have used this frame work: https://github.com/financialforcedev/ffhttp-googledrive. Everything works just fine only thing is not working is inserting the file inside the folder. I did check the code, and found that we need pass the parents[], I did that, still  attachment is stored in root folder.